# Find first instance of non-empty string in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

New to mongoDB. I am querying an array and I want to find the first instance where the imageUrl value is not an empty string. Currently I have this:

gallery.imageUrl = gallery.Galleryslides[0].imageUrl;

But this just pulls the first instance of imageUrl regardless of whether or not it's an empty string.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an example doc and expected output?

Comment: you should provide some schema,

Answer (score 0):

guessing that your schema is something like this

```
var gallery = {
    _id: "something",
    gallerySlides: [{
        imageUrl: "someUrl"
    }]
}
```

this query below will find all gallery that matches gallery's _id and all of gallerySlides that has imageUrl

```
db.galery.find({ _id: "something", "gallerySlides.imageUrl": {$ne: null} })
```

Comment: using find for _id: "something" is not rational cuz in mongodb there can be only one document with same _id, it means document _id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think You want to get list of galleries by some conditions
2) iterate these gallery documents and add first imageUrl of slide as cover of gallery.

I hope this example will be helpful:

```
const _ = require('lodash'); // don't forget install it: npm i --save lodash

var cursor = db
               .collection('gallery')
               .find({
                 gallerySlides: {$exists: true, $gt: {$size: 0}}
               });

var galleries = [];
cursor.each(function(gallery) {
  gallery.imageUrl = _.find(gallery.Galleryslides, 
                            function(slide) {return slide.imageUrl != ''});
  galleries.push(gallery);
});
```